# rails routing to controllers in a sub folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a requirement any url like:  `www.servername.com/api/foo/bar/parameters`

where:

- `api` is static
- `foo` is the controller
- `bar` is action
- `parameters` are params

to map to the controllers which are in `api` directory

> (*the api directory is in controllers directory*)

to achieve this I did the below code but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

```
 namespace :api do
   match "/api/:controller(/:action(/*params))", via: [:get, :post]
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is wrong with:

```
get '/api/:controller/(:action(/*path))'
```

which will generate the follwing route:

> GET    /api/:controller(/:action(/*path))(.:format) :controller#:action

Advanced dynamic rule is (see [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#dynamic_segments)):

```
get ':controller/(:action(/*path))', controller: /api\/[^\/]+/
```

leads to:

> api GET    :controller(/:action(/*path))(.:format) (?-mix:api/[^/]+)#:action

Comment: the result should be 
`GET    /api/:controller(/:action(/*path))(.:format) api/:controller#:action`

Comment: @ashwini and again

Comment: @ashwini whihch one?

Comment: actually wat i want with this routing is ... controllers which are in app/controllers/api directory should trigger

Comment: @ashwini the current version should trigger it i,e api/controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110511/discussion-between-ashwini-and--).

Answer (score 1):

You should have something similar to the following, and its better to have version in case you need to change later, so you may have v2 later:

```
scope 'api', module: :api, constraints: { format: :json } do
  namespace :v1 do
    match ":controller(/:action(/*params))", via: [:get, :post]
  end
end
```

note that `api` is not exist in the match route part its only in the scope,

after change try to run `rake routes` to check your routes how it looks like.

Comment: i ran rake routes and got this error `ArgumentError: :controller segment is not allowed within a namespace block`

Comment: you didn't tell where to go when its matched, you match clause should looks like `match "/students/:student_id", to:"students#show", via: :get` check for more details here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: when it is matched it should go to the controller which are in api folder

Comment: which one, you should chat controllers one by one you can't leave it dynamic that way

Answer (score 0):

If you have folder api inside the controllers folder, you will put:

```
namespace :api do
    match ":controller(/:action(/*params))", via: [:get, :post]
end
```

You put an /api/ in url that causing that routes point to:

www.servername.com/api/api/foo/bar/parameters

Important note: [Match deprecation](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5964)

Comment: i tried this getting this error `ArgumentError: :controller segment is not allowed within a namespace block`

Comment: Try using scope :api, path: 'api' instead of namespace

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
namespace :api do
   match ':controller/:action/*params', via: [:get, :post]
end
```

Comment: But it will go the controller in controllers directory, i want to match all the controller which are in app/controllers/api directory

Comment: You want to generate a common route for all controller inside api directory ?